# Avoid deleting multiple sub folders inside a folder on shell

Tags: bash, find

I have a folder hierarchy such as

```
A
|--B/C
|--D
|--E/F/G
|--P/Q/R
```

Now I want to avoid deleting Folder G and D. I am trying to write a shell command where it will delete everything else but D and G.

So after the command run it should look like this -

```
A
|--D
|--E/F/G
```

I tried using this but it did not work for me -

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'D' -a ! -name "E/F/G" -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Can someone please help here ?

Comment: When I ran the above find -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'D' -a ! -name "E/F/G" -exec rm -rf {} +. It deleted everything else other than 'D'. I want to have E/F/G as well.

Comment: Are there other files in E other than F, and in F other than G?

Comment: Try `find  ! -name '.' -a ! -name 'D' -a ! -name 'E' -a ! -name 'F' -a ! -name 'G' -exec -exec rm -rf {} +`

Comment: @oguzismail - Yes there are other files and folder in E and also some folder and files inside F and G

Comment: @fpmurphy - this command doesnt work because files inside D, G gets deleted. Only the folders remain. I dont want to delete files inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find ./A -depth -mindepth 1 ! \( -path "*/D*" -o -path "*/G*" \) -exec rm -d {} +
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ tree ./A
./A
├── aFile
├── B
│   ├── bFile
│   └── C
│       └── cFile
├── D
│   └── dFile
├── E
│   ├── eFile
│   └── F
│       ├── fFile
│       └── G
│           └── gFile
└── P
    ├── pFile
    └── Q
        ├── qFile
        └── R
            └── rFile

9 directories, 10 files

$ find ./A -depth -mindepth 1 ! \( -path "*/D*" -o -path "*/G*" \) \
    -exec rm -d {} + > /dev/null 2>&1

$ tree A
A
├── D
│   └── dFile
└── E
    └── F
        └── G
            └── gFile

4 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: this command doesnt work because files inside D, G gets deleted. Only the folders remain. I dont want to delete files inside them. I want files inside D and G to remain. Also by [EFG] -> Did you mean E/F/G ?

Comment: @Arnold this command does ***not*** delete any of the files. However, I did fix the `[EFG]` part.  I updated my proof of concept to show the files remain

Comment: Thanks for the help. From the above solution can it delete aFile, eFile, fFile ? All I care is D folder and things inside it and E/F/G folder and things inside G. So that mean I would want to keep all filder and folders in D and G only.

Comment: @Arnold Updated command based on your new requirements.  Note that in my proof of concept I redirected stderr to `/dev/null` because `rm` will complain that it cannot remove `./A/E/F` or `./A/E` because they are not empty (which is what you want.)  If this works, please accept answer

Comment: Thanks @Siege, your solution worked here. Thanks much appreciate it. Accepted the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

exclude=(
        'E/F/G'
        'D'
    )

while read -r dir
do
    flag=1
    for edir in "${exclude[@]}"
    do
        if [ "${edir#$dir}" != "$edir" ]
        then
            flag=0
        fi
    done

    [ $flag -eq 1 ] && rm -rf "$dir"

done <<< "$( find * )"
```

This may help. It won't work if your directory contains subdirs/files with newlines. I couldn't think of clean ways to do this solely with `find` though there might be some.

Basically, we iterate over output of `find *`.
Then we check for every input, the excluded dir shouldn't be a subdir. e.g., `E/F/G` is subdir of `E` and hence we need to exclude `E` as well.

Comment: Thanks Mihir, I tried this solution but it deleted files inside D and G. What I want is D folder and things inside it (could be files and other stuff) and E/F/G folder and things inside G. So that mean I would want to keep all filder and folders in D and G only

Comment: @Arnold, I guess you would need to update how exactly are you testing the same to say that it deletes all files. Update your exact directory structure please.

Comment: @Arnold, the only way it could happen is in a very rare case and that too if your dirs contain newlines. I have already mentioned it won't work if yours subdirs/files contain newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, try

```
find A -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'D' -a ! -name "E" -exec rm -rf {} +
```

When you don't know in which subdirectory G is hiding, first find G.

```
find A -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'D' -a ! -name "$(find A -type d -name 'G' | cut -d/ -f2)" \
     -exec rm -rf {} +
```